# Find the projection of the straight line $(x-1)/2 = (y-1)/3 = (z+1)/-1$ on the plane $x+y+2z = 6$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry, solid-geometry

I have got the answer, seeking intuition from
https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer/find-the-equations-of-the-projection-of-the-line-x-1-2y-1-3z-2-4-on-the-plane-2x-y-4z1-1116852

The answer is $\frac{x-5}{3} = \frac{y-7}{5} = \frac{z+3}{-4}$

Why didn't my initial approach work ?

Projection of a line on a plane is line (if original line was not normal to it)
Let its dc's : $l,m,n$. It will lie in plane, so

$l + m + 2n = 0          \:     ...(1)$

$\cos \theta = \frac{2l + 3m -n}{\sqrt{14}}      \   ...(2)$,    $\theta$ is angle between original line and plane

$\sin \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{14 \cdot 6}} (2.1 + 3.1 + (-1).2) \             ...(3)$

EDIT:

$ \sin(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{3/2}}{\sqrt{14}} $

$ \cos(\theta) = \frac{5 / \sqrt2}{\sqrt{14}} = \frac {2l + 3m -n}{\sqrt{14}}$  ... from (2)

$ \implies 2l + 3m -n =  \frac{5}{\sqrt2} $           ..(4)

how can I find ratio of $l,m,n$ from (3) and (4)?

(Since dc's, so can also use $l^2 + m^2 + n^2 = 1$ - it's a post thought, but no help)

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting. I'll learn it on the way. Do share an easy link, if possible

Comment: Put math between dollar signs `$..$`. Use upright characters for functions with `\sin` or `\mathrm{sin}` and use `\frac{a}{b}` for fractions. The culry braces group things. Use `_` for subscript and `^` for superscript.

Comment: It does work and will give you the direction vector of the projection but you also need a point on the line. How were you planning to find that?

Comment: Also for mathjax, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @MathLover I am sorry. I fail to get how it gives direction vectors. I have made some EDITs. And yes, I will need a point on line. But, I was just trying to get dr's at this stage. Anyways, thank you :)

Comment: OK see my answer on finding direction vector.

Comment: Good to see you attempted mathjax in your edit. Please note for square root you use \sqrt and for ==> you can use \implies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding direction vector of the line using the method you started with is possible. But we need additional steps to find a point on the line. But to answer your question, here is how we can find direction vector using the method you started with.

Say unit direction vector of the line is $ \ \hat d = (l, m, n)$.

As the line is in the plane $x + y + 2z = 6$, dot product of its direction vector with the normal vector to the plane must be zero.

$l + m + 2n = 0 \implies m + 2n = -l\tag1$

If angle between original line and the normal vector to the plane is $\theta, \  $ then

$(1 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot -1) = \sqrt6 \cdot \sqrt{14} \cos\theta \implies \displaystyle \cos\theta = \sqrt{\frac{3}{28}}, \  \sin \theta = \frac{5}{\sqrt{28}}$

As the angle between the original line and its projection onto the plane is $(90^0 - \theta)$,

$\displaystyle  2l + 3m - n = \sqrt{14} \cdot \frac{5}{\sqrt{28}} = \frac{5}{\sqrt2} \implies 3m-n = \frac{5}{\sqrt2} - 2l\tag2$

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$\displaystyle m = \frac{5 (\sqrt2-l)}{7} \land n = - \frac{5 + l \sqrt2}{7\sqrt2}$

As $(l. m. n)$ is unit vector, $l^2+m^2+n^2 = 1 \implies l^2 + (\frac{5 (\sqrt2-l)}{7})^2 + (- \frac{5 + l \sqrt2}{7\sqrt2})^2 = 1$

This simplifies to, $ \ \displaystyle l^2 - \frac{3 \sqrt2 l}{5} + \frac{9}{50} = 0 \implies (l - \frac{3}{5\sqrt2})^2 = 0$

So we get, $l = \frac{3}{5\sqrt2} \land m = \frac{5}{5\sqrt2} \land n = - \frac{4}{5 \sqrt2}  $

That gives direction of line as $(3, 5, -4)$.

Comment: Thank you , now I see.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward method is:

1. Take the normal of the plane : $\vec{i}$ + $\vec{j}$ + 2.$\vec{k}$ ( A line with direction cosines <1, 1, 2>)
2. Take two points on the given line; for example A: <1, 1, -1>, B :<3, 4, -2>
3. Solve for line with direction cosines <1, 1, 2>, passing through A and B and find their intersection with the plane. This will give you 2 points on the plane that are projections of A and B. Let them be A'($A'_x, A'_y, A'_z$) and B'($B'_x, B'_y, B'_z$)
4. The projection of the line on the plane is $\frac{x - A'_x}{A'_x - B'_x}$ = $\frac{y - A'_y}{A'_y - B'_y}$ = $\frac{z - A'_z}{A'_z - B'_z}$

Hope this helps

Comment: "Solve for line with direction cosines <1, 1, 2>, passing through A and B and satisfying the plane equation" doesn't make sense to me. If a line passes through A and B, it cannot satisfy the plane equation, because A and B don't satisfy the plane equation. Perhaps you mean to find two lines (one through A, and one through B) and then find a point on each line satisfying the plane equation?

Comment: Yes, I meant to find an intersection 
1. of line passing through A and B with the direction cosines
2. and the Plane
That's why I said, upon solving we will get two points that are the projection of A and B on the plane

Comment: thank you @thecuriousguy . I finally came to this method, but it was not my first approach, which didn't work as I had expected.